# Sums of powers of exponentials

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

Suppose that the identity
$$e^{i \theta_1} + \ldots + e^{i \theta_n} = e^{i k \theta_1} + \ldots + e^{i k \theta_n}$$
holds true $\forall k \neq 0$.

Is then true that we must have $\theta_i = 0$, $\forall i$?

I'm having a hard time seeing why it has to be true.

Comment: I have edited the question in a more direct way.

Comment: $z_1+\cdots z_n=z_1^2+\cdots z_n^2=z_1^3+\cdots z_n^3=\cdots=z_1^k+\cdots z_n^k$ is not possible for $k>n$.

Comment: Ah I think that might work! Can you elaborate on why that's true?

Answer (score 0):

The condition $\forall k > 0 $ seems wrong to me. Indeed, restricting to a simpler case:

$$e^{i\theta_1} + e^{i\theta_2} = e^{ik\theta_1} + e^{ik\theta_2}$$

Choosing $\theta_1 = 0$ and $\theta_2 = \pi/2$ you get

$$-1 = e^{ik\pi/2}$$

Which doesn't hold unless $k\in\Omega \subset \mathbb{Z}$, $k = \{\pm 2, \pm 6, \pm 10, \pm 14, \ldots\}$

Now reason in reverse mode: for this choice of $k$ which as you see is not zero, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are not both zero.

*Note*: I won't delete this answer for I wrote it whilst the question was asked in a lightly blurry way.

Comment: As you see in my example, in reverse: for _this_ choice of  $k$, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ could not be both zero.

Comment: I'm still not sure I'm understanding this. For your $\theta_1, \theta_2$ it's not true that $e^{i \theta_1} + e^{i \theta_2} = e^{i k \theta_1} + e^{i k \theta_2}$ for all $k$, so this doesn't seem to provide a counterexample. The claim I want is that if the sum is the same for all $k$ then the $\theta_i = 0$

Comment: That's what I said. Choose for example $k = 2$. Then you will see that $\theta_1 = 0$ and $\theta_2 = \pi/2$ satisfy the equation, not being both zero.

Comment: But that is only for $k=2$. I am saying it needs to happen for all $k$. This example does not satisfy the equation for $k=3$.

Comment: You said it must hold for all $k$. If it doesn't for $k = 2$ then it doesn't _for all_ $k$.

Comment: Unless you're saying that _you want_ a priori that the equation is supposed to be valid $\forall k$... That's another question...

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you've proved the contrapositive of my claim but I don't think so. The contrapositive is that if the $\theta_i$ are not all $0$ then there exists a $k$ such that the sums are not equal. In this case, $k=3$ exists so there is nothing inconsistent with the claim I'm trying to show

Comment: Yes, the assumption is that the equation is true for all $k$